# Calling a method in one JS module and returning data to another

Tags: javascript

Trying to master the modular programming pattern in JS. I'm having difficulties calling a method in one module -- which returns true or false depending on conditions -- from another module and using the data returned.

This is a cut down version of my first module:

```
var stAuthentication = (function() {
    return {
        someMethod: function() {
            ///
        },
        isAuthenticated: function() {
            var authenticated;
            ajax_isAuthenticated = $.ajax({
                url: root+'/assets/scripts/php/app/isAuthenticated',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text'
            });
            ajax_isAuthenticated.done(function(response) {
                authenticated = response;
                console.log("Ajax request returned "+authenticated);
            });
            ajax_isAuthenticated.fail(function(response) {
                console.log("Ajax request (ajax_isAuthenticated) failed.");
            });
            if (authenticated == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;    
            }
        },
        someOtherMethod: function() {
            ///
        }
    }
})();
```

As you can see, the method in question is **isAuthenticated()**. This basically sends an AJAX request to the server where it checks if the user is logged in and returns 1 or 0. I have tested the response from this and it works as it should. My issue is with the next module, where I'll be calling the method in the first example to determine if the user is logged in before running a task in the second module. Here it is:

```
var stReadLater = (function() {
    var elements, quantity;
    return {
        someMethod: function() {
            //
        },
        saveItem: function() {
            if (stAuthentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                console.log("Signed in");
                // user is signed in so use this feature
            } else {
                console.log("Not signed in");
                // ask user to sign in before using this feature
            }
        },
        someOtherMethod: function() {
            //
        }
    }
})();
```

The actually location of the issue is this few lines I think, from the first module:

```
if (authenticated == 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;    
}
```

First of all, I noticed that it was always returning false. After more playing around, I noticed that `authenticated` was `undefined` which led me to move `var authenticated` around the scope but no luck. I also tried `this.authenticated` without luck, too.

I know I'm fairly close but I have tried so many different variations I've totally lost it. What is the correct way of doing this?

**========================**
**THE FIX**

I was checking the `authenticated` variable before AJAX had set it. Thanks to @willma for the suggestions. This is what I did if anybody else comes across this:

```
isAuthenticated: function() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    ajax_isAuthenticated = $.ajax({
        url: root+'/assets/scripts/php/app/isAuthenticated',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text'
    });
    ajax_isAuthenticated.done(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response)
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

and then in the second module:

```
saveItem: function() {
    $.when(stAuthentication.isAuthenticated()).then(function(response) {
        if (response == 0) {
            console.log("Not signed in");
        } else {
            console.log("Is signed in");    
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up synchronous and asynchronous code. `isAuthenticated` will always return false because the function will always return before either of the `done` or `fail` callbacks can be called.

Your entire function is basically doing this:

```
var authenticated;
if (authenticated == 0) { // This is the case because undefined == 0 -> true
  return false;
} else {
  return true;    
}
```

You have two solutions. Either the stReadLater object can pass a callback function like this:

```
function done() {
  console.log("Signed in");
}
function fail() {
  console.log("Not signed in");
}

stReadLater.saveItem = function() {
  stAuthentication.isAuthenticated(done, fail);
}
```

Then is your authentication module:

```
var stAuthentication.isAuthenticated = function(done, fail) {
  ajax_isAuthenticated = $.ajax({
    url: root+'/assets/scripts/php/app/isAuthenticated',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text'
  });
  ajax_isAuthenticated.done(done);
  ajax_isAuthenticated.fail(fail);
}
```

Or you can use promises. I find promises more elegant. It's worth [reading about them](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I went with your second suggestion and used `when()` and `then()`. See my question edit for revised code. I'm truly kicking myself as to why I missed the cause of this problem. Never mind. I won't again.